# Cannot get custom attribute from joined tables

Tags: product, configurable-product, price

```
$componentQuantityCollection = Mage::getModel('modules/modules')->getCollection();

$componentQuantityCollection->join(array('product' => 'catalog/product'), 'main_table.kit_sku = product.sku', '*', 'left');

foreach ($componentQuantityCollection as $kit) {
    Mage::log($kit->getKitOrderStock());
}
```

This returns null every time.  I'm sure these products have these attributes defined in the back end.  What am I doing wrong?

This generates the following sql:

> SELECT `main_table`.* , `product`.* FROM `modules` AS
>   `main_table`  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON
>   main_table.kit_sku = product.sku

The custom attribute is called 'kit_order_stock'.

Comment: kit_order_stock is a product attribute or a column in your `modules` table?

Comment: @Marius a product attribute.

Comment: Then, it's normal you to get it's value. The values is not stored in the `catalog_product_entity` table and you are joining only that table. and not the one that stores the values for your attribute.

Comment: please show code of customer attribute  installer thus understand  attribute resource model etcs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are expecting the results of the collection to be product instances I think you should better start with the product collection and then join your module table.
Try something like this (untested code).

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('kit_order_stock');//you can use ->addAttributeToSelect('*') if you want to add all attributes to the collection
$collection->joinTable('modules', 'kit_sku=sku', array('*'));
```

**[EDIT]**
The code above works but some conditions have to be met.
 - If you are calling this code from the backend it works. At least it did for me.
 - If you are calling it from the frontend and the flat catalog is disabled it works.
 - if you are calling it from the frontend, the flat catalog is enabled and your attribute is marked as "use in product listing" it works (just make sure your indexes are up to date).
 - if you are calling it from the frontend, the flat catalog is enabled and your attribute is not marked as "use in product listing" it does not work.

Also make sure the products your get from the collection have a value set for the attribute `kit_order_stock`.

Comment: When I try to get the custom attribute from the product collection it still will not show up using your method.  Things like sku, id, kitsku (which is within the modules table) are present -- but not the custom attribute.

Comment: OK. I'll try a better answer tomorrow.

Comment: @easymoden00b. See my update to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$componentQuantityCollection = Mage::getModel('modules/modules')->getCollection();

$componentQuantityCollection->join(array('product' => 'catalog/product'), 'main_table.kit_sku = product.sku', '*', 'left');


$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'kit_order_stock');

$componentQuantityCollection->join(
    'catalog_product_entity_int', 
    'product.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id and attribute_id='.$attributeId, 
    'kit_order_stock', 
    'left');


foreach ($componentQuantityCollection as $kit) {
    Mage::log($kit->getKitOrderStock());
}
```

Comment: okay the attribute is in catalog_product_entity_int. How do I get these values? The attribute ID is 631

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Hardcoding an attribute id or similar within a select is always a bad idea. Magento should know what to do.

Comment: @LukeRodgers thanks for pointing that, updated the answer